# Why input/output ground is different and connect them by 0.1 ohm resistor?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

This is a sample schematic at On Semiconductor [TL494 datasheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/TL494-D.PDF).

[image]

It's a buck converter using pnp BJT (Tip 32A) as a switch.
What I'm interested in is the 0.1 ohm resistor (in yellow circle).
I havn't seen this type of buck converter curcuit that has separate grounds and connected by a resistor.

What's the benefit of adding this resistor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the 100mohm resistor is for current sensing on pin 16 for the purpose of current limiting. Putting the IC ground on it as well causes the IC's current consumption to be added to this.

[image: TI SLVA001E reference circuit]

TI's document SLVA001E, "Designing Switching Voltage Regulators With the TL494", shows combined grounds on page 24 (above). Whether this represents an error on ON's part is up for debate, but keep in mind that the IC's power is supplied independently from the high voltage and *not* from the load side of the inductor.

Comment: Thanks. I tested on breadboard. 0.1 ohm limits output current to 1.4A, 0.05 ohm limits 2.1A.